# Range query on results in useless highlighting

Tags: solr, highlight, solrj

I am using a query containing a Range clause and I am using highlighting to get the list of values that match the range query. 
All examples below were using the appropriate Solr Admin Server Query page.

The query using **Solr v7.7.1** produces CORRECT and useful results:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 143,
    "params": {
      "q": "description:N22",
      "hl": "true",
      "hl.fl": "*",
      "_": "1566909611857"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "9901020319A02-N22",
        "groupId": "9901020319A02",
        "urn": "N22",
        "specification": "nominal",
        "owningGroupId": "9901020319A02",
        "description": "N22, Gustav, Fringe, MALE",
... lots more docs, then 
    ] 
  }, 
... 
   "highlighting": {
    "9901020319A02-N22": {
      "description": [
        "<em>N22</em>, Gustav, Fringe, MALE"
      ],
      "nominalUrn_t": [
        "<em>N22</em>"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

When i tried with range query the problem is with the highlighting which is effectively empty. I don't know what 
values in each document actually matched the query:

```
   "highlighting": {
    "9901020319A02-N23": {},
    "9901020319A02-N22": {},
    "9901020319A02-N24": {},
    "9901020319A02-N25": {}
  }
}
```

---

Changing to using "&hl.method=unified", the highlighting looks like:

```
  "highlighting": {
    "9901020319A02-N23": {
      "id": [],
      "groupId": [],
      "urn": [],
      "specification": [],
      "owningGroupId": [],
      "description": [],
      "group_t": [],
      "exhibitUrn_t": [],
      "labelDescription_t": [],
```

*** Closer but still no useful values

---

All variations of hl specs or other query parameters do not fix the problem with range queries.
The highlight portion of the response is effectively "empty"

Comment: What is your range query?

Comment: hi @MatsLindh  , I am searching like "urn:[N22 TO N25]". 4 Results is there but highlight portion of the response is "[ ]". This is the query: localhost:8983/solr/v16/select?q=urn:%5BN22+TO+N25%5D&hl=true&hl.fl=* –